# Prove this process is Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

> Let $X_n$ be largest number of first n throws of a fair six-sided die, show that $X = \{X_n: n\ge 1\}$ is homogeneous Markov chain

My try:
Let $Y_i$ denote the number of $i$th throw, then $X_n = \max\{Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n\}$,
$$P(X_{n+1} = j | X_n = i, X_{n-1} = x_{n-1},...,X_1 = x_1) = P(\max\{X_n, Y_{n+1}\} = j | X_n = i, X_{n-1} = x_{n-1},...,X_1 = x_1)$$

Since $\max\{X_n,Y_{n+1}\} = j$  only depends on $X_n$ and $Y_{n+1}$ , it seems that

$$P(\max\{X_n, Y_{n+1}\} = j | X_n = i, X_{n-1} = x_{n-1},...,X_1 = x_1) = P(\max\{X_n, Y_{n+1}\} = j | X_n = i)$$

If so, why?

About homogeneity, when trying to verify $P(X_{n+1} = j | X_n = i) = P(X_2 = j | X_1 = i)$, it seems that computation is complicated since you have to check corner case $i=1  \ or \ 6.$

Any hint?

Comment: Either $Y_{n+1} = j$ or $X_n = j$. Show that in both cases the Markov condition holds.

Comment: Either $Y_{n+1} = j$ or $X_n = j$. Show that in both cases the Markov condition holds.